# Reducing list (dr racket)

Tags: racket

I am a beginner in Dr Racket and now I am looking for a solution to reduce nested lists.

For example:
`+ 0 (list 1 2 (list 3 (list 4 5) 6) 7 (list (list 8)) empty 9))` 
should produce 45.

My current function only works for normal lists, but as soon as there is a list in the list, it doesn´t work anymore.

```
(define (reduce fun neutral lst)
  (cond
    ((empty? lst) neutral)
     (else
          (fun (car lst)
           (reduce fun neutral (rest lst))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must consider the case where `(car lst)` is also a list. In that case, you will need to reduce `(car lst)` too, before applying `fun`.

```
(define (reduce fun neutral lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)
     neutral]
    [(list? (car lst))
     (fun (reduce fun neutral (car lst))
          (reduce fun neutral (rest lst)))]
    [else
     (fun (car lst)
          (reduce fun neutral (rest lst)))]))
```